# How to use Honeywell NBP Series Sensor with Arduino

Tags: sensors, analogread, resistor

I am trying to use a HONEYWELL NBPDANN100PAUNV Pressure Sensor.

I found an example here http://www.circuitstoday.com/interfacing-pressure-sensor-arduino

[image]

As this example says as instrumentation amplifier based on quad op-amp LM324 is used for conditioning the output voltage from the pressure sensor.

```cpp
int sensor=A0; 
int dig_out;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(sensor,INPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop(){
  if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
      dig_out=analogRead(sensor); // reads the input voltage
    Serial.print("Pressure Sensor "); // prints "Pressure Sensor"
    Serial.print(dig_out);
    Serial.print("\n");
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

But when I make this circuit and connect to Arduino it just give output about 5, I give the external air pressure but value not change.

Can any one help me Interfacing this type of sensor to Arduino.